# generating series- K Fibonnaci (Java)

Tags: java, fibonacci, series

new here.
I am trying to solve this problem [here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/KFIB).
I am using java and i dont know why it fails me in most test cases. Here is my solution

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k,n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        k = sc.nextInt();
        long ans;
        long term[]=new long[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
         if(i<k)
             term[i]=1;
         else if(i==k)
             term[i]=k;
         else
         {
             term[i]=0;
            for(int j=i-k;j<i;j++)
                term[i]+=term[j];
         }
        } 
        ans=term[n-1]%1000000007;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

i pass 4 test cases but fail in others. i cannot seem to figure out why.
A similar solution has been accepted which is [this](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/16352197).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: Is long large enough to hold the terms?

Comment: there is a good chance that the terms are too big to fit in long, which is why the solution that you linked mods every term by 1000000007 (given how `(a%b + c%b) % b == (a+c) % b`)

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
public class Main{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k,n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    k = sc.nextInt();
    long ans;
    long term[]=new long[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     if(i<k)
         term[i]=1;
     else if(i==k)
         term[i]=k;
     else
     {
         term[i]=0;
        for(int j=i-k;j<i;j++){
            term[i]+=term[j];
            term[i]%=1000000007;    
            }
     }
    } 
    ans=term[n-1]%1000000007;
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

}

it worked and passed all the test cases (this solution in also said by njzk2)

Comment: Ohk. Thanks guys 